# Using custom fields to dynamically change Wordpress Menus

Tags: wordpress, navigation, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a multi location  site on WordPress. Evey location has the same structure which is

```
example.com/location1/home,
example.com/location1/about
example.com/location1/contact. 
example.com/location2/home,
example.com/location2/about
example.com/location2/contact
```

I have created a "location" name custom field to dynamically change on every location page but don't know how can I add this to the menu so that I can create links that work for every location using the custom field.

The plan would be to use example.com/location/home for all locations and for it to pull location1 or location2 or location35 from the custom field that would be added to every page

Tried different php codes I found but nothing works